# Перетаскивание файлов из проводника в программу в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-n-drop, catel

У меня есть приложение на WPF + Catel + MVVM.
Мне необходимо реализовать перетаскивание файлов из проводника в программу с получением полного пути к файлу. Как это возможно реализовать? Есть ли какие либо библиотеки для этого, поддерживающие модель MVVM? Смотрел в сторону библиотеки [**gong-wpf-dragdrop**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/), но как понял она не поддерживает перетаскивание из проводника в программу.

**UPD1.**

Спасибо @Andrew, но в вашем ответе требуется чтобы я обработал события в code-behind. И хотя это даст мне нужные данные, у меня нет возможности передать их в мою модель представления. Мне нужен синтаксис для:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelObservableCollection}"

          AllowDrop = "True"

          Drop = "{Binding TheDropHandlerInTheViewModel, PassTheDropEventArgs}"

          DragOver = "{Binding TheDragOverHandlerInTheViewModel, PassTheDrageEventArgs}">

</ListView>
```

Comment: `gong-wpf-dragdrop` - прекрасно работала, когда я ее юзал - кидал фотки на WPF форму без проблем.

Comment: @Сергей может у вас остался пример как перетаскивать файлы из проводника на форму? Я сколько не пробовал, форма никак не реагировала на перетаскиваемые файлы

Comment: ок, как домой попаду найду кину

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение `gong-wpf-dragdrop` (кстати его пилят, версия 2.0 будет поддерживать .Net.Core 3).

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
             dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
             dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"
             >

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDropTarget
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;

        var dataObject = dropInfo.Data as IDataObject;

        dropInfo.Effects = dataObject != null && dataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) 
            ? DragDropEffects.Copy 
            : DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        var dataObject = dropInfo.Data as DataObject;
        if (dataObject != null && dataObject.ContainsFileDropList())
        {
            var files = dataObject.GetFileDropList();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Items.Add(file);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного задержался с ответом я) Спасибо большое) Делал точно также и не работало. Создал проект с нуля - все работает. Потом переустановил nuget пакет в проекте и все заработало, видимо в нем ошибка была) Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ImagePanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
  {
    // можно же перетянуть много файлов, так что....
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    // делаешь что-то
  }
}
```

ну и про XAML не забываем:

```
<StackPanel Name="ImagePanel" Drop="ImagePanel_Drop" AllowDrop="true">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

то есть важно наличие обеих атрибутов:

```
Drop="ImagePanel_Drop" AllowDrop="true"
```

Comment: спасибо, я внес поправку в вопрос

Comment: @Leksor А в чем конкретно проблема? Сендер есть? Есть. Доступ до dataSource сендера есть? Есть.  Так почему нельзя внести нужные правки в данные через метот там, где коментарий "делаешь что-то".